# using Dapper with '?'

Tags: c#, db2, dapper

I'm attempting to use Dapper to communicate with a DB2 server. The DB2 server doesn't support named parameters out of the box. It expects a question mark in the query for each parameter. Is there a way to support this with Dapper? Maybe Dapper can replace all `@Name` stuff with `?` before calling the query? And if so, does Dapper generate the parameters in order?

If not, it seems that the newer DB2 client drivers support named parameters, but it is off by default. I can't figure out how to turn it on. I tried adding that parameter to the `db2cli.ini` [COMMON] section on my client with no change in behavior. That was for the `OleDB` driver.

Update: I then tried the .NET driver. That one seems to parse the variable names, but I still get a strange error when running:

> {"ERROR [07004] [IBM][DB2/NT64] SQL0313N  The number of variables in
>   the EXECUTE statement, the number of variables in the OPEN statement,
>   or the number of arguments in an OPEN statement for a parameterized
>   cursor is not equal to the number of values required."}

My statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO XD.ALERT (PERFORMANCE_ID, CATEGORY, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, DATETIME) VALUES(1234, :Level, :AlertID, :AlertDesc, :DateTime)
```

Does an INSERT count as an EXECUTE? As far as I can tell I have four parameters in the query and four in the command object being used. (I'm using `SqlMapper.cs` directly and I can see everything in the debugger.)

Comment: Yes, `INSERT` will count as an exec (actually, any TSQL would); `:` is explicitly recognized as a parameter specifier - can you perhaps indicate what the parameters  object looks like? i.e. is it `new { Level = 123, AlertID = "Foo", ... }`, or ... ? Basically, can you show the same TSQL but with the C# code you are using to call it? Re "in order"; that is tricky.. it is mainly built around named values via reflection, and reflection doesn't really have any particular order :(

Comment: I'm not using an anonymous type. Like I said, I can see that everything is correct right when the command is executed. I'm going to chalk this one up to DB2 Client buginess (as apparently named parameters are a new thing for them).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    public void SaveAlert(int? level, int? alertId, string alertDesc, DateTime date)
    {            
        _conn.Execute("INSERT INTO XD.ALERT(PERFORMANCE_ID, CATEGORY, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, DATETIME) VALUES(1234, @Level, @AlertID, @AlertDesc, @DateTime)",                
            new {
                Level = level,
                AlertId = alertId,
                AlertDesc = alertDesc,
                DateTime = date
            });
    }
```

Comment: I'm no longer in a situation to be able to test this. Sorry.